# Invalid Mark Error while trying to read mp3 files javaZoom

Tags: java, ffmpeg, mp3, javasound

I'm trying to load an mp3 that I've modified with ffmpeg by doing 
`"ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp3 -y -ar 48000 converted.mp3`
, but when I try to read the file using javaZoom, I get this error

```
java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:454)
    at org.tritonus.share.sampled.file.TAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(TAudioFileReader.java:330)
    at javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.file.MpegAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.file.MpegAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1060)
    at VoiceBot.queueAudio(VoiceBot.java:123)
    at VoiceBot.onMessageReceived(VoiceBot.java:104)
```

This problem did not occur with normal unmodified files and didn't even occur with some of the modified files. And so I believe it may have to with the file size. Because I'm chaning the sampling rates of the files from 44.1 kHz to 48 kHz, which is expanding the file size.

This problem had occurred before as seen in the previous thread: [Error while playing some MP3s using JavaZOOM BasicPlayer classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046136/error-while-playing-some-mp3s-using-javazoom-basicplayer-classes)

However, the solution to the problem was to mp3spi1.9.5. The problem is, that's the version of it I'm using and I still have the problem. I am also using jl1.0.1 and tritonous0.3.6.

Is this a problem with JLayer? Should I move to a different mp3 reading library, or is this an easily fixable problem.

EDIT: So I've managed to work around this by lowering the bitrate of the converted mp3 files. I would very much like to not have to do this and actually have full quality. But hopefully this is helpful to any one who is trying to help.

Comment: If you're on macOS/Windows, [one of these](http://www.tagtraum.com/sampledsp.html) may work with the original bitrate.

Comment: Why resample the MP3 files in the first place?

Comment: I want to resample mp3 files, because I'm streaming them to discord using JDA, which sends audio at a sampling rate of 48 kHz while most files I have are 44.1kHz and so they sound messed up if I don't resample them.